# Building variables during an object loop to retrieve data from preexisting variables

Tags: php, oop, variables, object, foreach

**Preamble**

I am building a new application from the ground-up and I am trying to implement the DRY principle as much as possible.

I am trying to make my query building a little more dynamic, so I am having to define variables on-the-fly by using the column names from the database table that I am currently working with.

**The Problem**

Defining the variables on the fly is only working for half of my code. For example, the `UPDATE` code is working fine:

```
// Get the data.
$data = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM `{$table}` WHERE `ID` = {$id}")->firstResult();

// Build the SQL.
$sql  = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET ";

foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
    $sql .= "`$key` = '{${$key}}', "; 
}

$sql  = trimSQL($sql); // Removes the final ', '
$sql .= "WHERE `id` = {$id}";
```

However, the `INSERT` code is not:

```
// Get the column names from the DB.
$data = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = '{$table}'")->results();

// Build the SQL.
$sql  = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";

foreach($data as $d) { 
    $sql .= ($d->COLUMN_NAME ? "'{$d->COLUMN_NAME}', " : $sql); 
}

$sql  = trimSQL($sql); // Removes the final ', '
$sql .= ') VALUES (';

// This is the problem loop.
foreach($data as $d) { 
    $sql .= ($d->COLUMN_NAME ? "`{${$d->COLUMN_NAME}}`, " : $sql); 
}

$sql  = trimSQL($sql); // Removes the final ', '
$sql .= ')';

return $sql;
```

The above is returning the following:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (``, ``, ``)
```

So, the first `foreach` is working as expected but the second one isn't.

The variables that I am trying to define are being presented as if they're empty, when they're not. I use the same form names and variable names as the DB column names so that I can automate the process.

Even when I have explicitly defined the variables `$col1` up at the top of the page, it's still not pulling the data through.

The concept for add/edit is virtually the same. However, with adding data we haven't already got the table structure and have to go about it in a different kind of way.

However, I know that there's no issue with anything DB related because it's spitting out the column names for the first loop as expected.

This leads me to think that the issue must lie with defining the variables on-the-fly from an object, but I don't know...

Comment: Did you realise **you are also using  back-ticks `` for column values**? You may want to test what I posted below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly don't believe you must have broken your vow to DRY if you did it like so:

```
    <?php

        // Get the column names from the DB.
        $data = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = '{$table}'")->results();

        // Build the SQL.
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";

        foreach($data as $d) {
            $tblVal = ($tv=$d->COLUMN_NAME)? "`" . $tv . "`, " : $sql; 
            $sql .= $tblVal;
        }

        $sql  = trimSQL($sql); // Removes the final ', '
        $sql .= ') VALUES (';

        // This is the problem loop.
        foreach($data as $d) {
            $colVal = ($cn=$d->COLUMN_NAME)? "'" . $$cn . "', " : $sql; 
            $sql .= $colVal;   
        }

        $sql  = trimSQL($sql); // Removes the final ', '
        $sql .= ')';

        return $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for the insert is that you use ` instead of `'` (single quote) to wrap the values. Also, the result for the columns selection will be a single array with all the columns of the given table.

Change your code to:

```
foreach($data as $columnName) { 
    $sql .= "'" . ${$columnName} . "', "; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you - you're right, that is a problem, but it's not fixing *the* problem. Now I get `('', '', '')`

Comment: You should verify if your first query is returning the column names correctly.. In the update case you are using the column from the selection of a row, but in the insert query the selection is different.. just var_dump $data to see what it holds